# $\cap_{n}{ (C_n + D_n)} = \cap_{n}{C_n} + \cap_{n}{D_n}.$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. By $w$ we shall indicate the weak topology on $X$.

> Let $\{C_n\}$ consist of $w$-compact and $\{D_n\}$ of $w$-closed subsets of $X$. Assume
>   that $\{C_n\}$ and $\{D_n\}$  are both nonincreasing.
>
> Then:
>   $$\cap_{n}{ (C_n + D_n)} = \cap_{n}{C_n} + \cap_{n}{D_n}.$$

***Proof:***

Evidently, the right-hand side is contained in the left side. The proof of the
converse inclusion is straightforward:

let $x$ be an element of the intersection on the left, i.e., for every $n$ there exist $c_n \in C_n$ and $d_n \in D_n$ with $x = c_n+d_n$. Now by $w$-compactness of $C_1$ and the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, a subsequence $\{c_{n_j}\}$  of $\{c_{n}\}$ will converge to some $c \in X$. Of course, then $\{d_{n_j}\}$ converges to $x-c$. It follows immediately from the monotone inclusions that $c\in \cap_n C_n$ and $x -c \in \cap_nD_n$.

***My problem:***

Why: "By $w$-compactness of $C_1$ and the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, a subsequence $\{c_{n_j}\}$  of $\{c_{n}\}$ will converge to some $c \in X$"?

Answer (score 1):

Compactness of $C_1$ is suffcient because $C_n\supseteq C_{n+1}$ for all $n$ is part of the hypothesis and therefore $c_n\in C_1$ for all $n$.

Comment: $\{C_n\}$ is nonincreasing  but not decreasing. Can we say that all nonincreasing sequence is decreasing?

Comment: @AbdessamadEl Non-increasing usually means $C_n\supseteq C_{n+1}$ (and if one uses that word, decreasing is often taken to mean $C_{n}\supsetneq C_{n+1}$). The condition $C_n \not\subseteq C_{n+1}$ for a sequence $C_n$ is basically useless, so it doesn't make sense to have a word for it.

Comment: @AbdessamadEl English mathematics has the annoying kink of using *nondecreasing* as a synonym of *weakly increasing* (the idea is that it should mean something like "never decreasing").

Comment: @s.harp.  Thank you. I have one last question, please: Why $c\in \cap_n C_n$?

Comment: @Gae.S Thank you.

Comment: @AbdessamadEl The topology is Hausdorff and, for all $m$, $c_n\in C_m$ eventually.

Comment: I don't understand you, can you do a little proof?